# Format date with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-parsing

I have a string in this format:

```
var testDate = "Fri Apr 12 2013 19:08:55 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
```

I would like to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) get it in this format `mm/dd/yyyy : 04/12/2013` for display.

I tried to do it using this method,

```
moment(testDate,'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Which errors and says `there is no such method called replace`? Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

---

#### Edit

I should also mention that I am using a pre-packaged version of *Moment.js*, packaged for *Meteor.js*

```
Object [object Date] has no method 'replace' : The Exact error from the console
```

Stack Trace:

```
 at makeDateFromStringAndFormat (http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/moment/lib/moment/moment.js?b4e3ac4a3d0794023a4410e7941c3e179398b5b0:539:29)
    at moment (http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/moment/lib/moment/moment.js?b4e3ac4a3d0794023a4410e7941c3e179398b5b0:652:24)
    at populateProfileForEdit (http://127.0.0.1:3000/client/views/home/administration/directory/profiles/profiles.js?acfff908a6a099f37312f62892a22b40f82e5e0f:147:25)
    at Object.Template.profile_personal.rendered (http://127.0.0.1:3000/client/views/home/administration/directory/profiles/profiles.js?acfff908a6a099f37312f62892a22b40f82e5e0f:130:13)
    at Spark.createLandmark.rendered (http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/templating/deftemplate.js?b622653d121262e50a80be772bf5b1e55ab33881:126:42)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?45c746f38023ceb80745f4b4280457e15f058bbc:384:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/underscore/underscore.js?867d3653d53e9c7a171483edbcad9670e12288c7:79:11)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?45c746f38023ceb80745f4b4280457e15f058bbc:382:7
    at _.extend.flush (http://127.0.0.1:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?9642a93ae1f8ffa8eb1c2475b198c764f183d693:231:11)
```

Comment: Are you using `replace()` in your code?  If not, the plugin your using is inappropriately calling a nonexistent method.

Comment: I have updated my question with exact error and stack trace with the method that calls 'replace'. I am not directly calling replace at all

Answer (score 802, accepted):

The 2nd argument to `moment()` is a [*parsing* format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) rather than an *display* format.

For that, you want the [`.format()` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
moment(testDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Also note that case does matter. For Month, Day of Month, and Year, the format should be uppercase.

Comment: Excellent. I initially tried to use it like this moment().format(), which failed. Thanks

Comment: var obj = {end_date: moment($scope.activity.endDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')};

Comment: @MichaelCalkins Sorry. What is that for? And, why the additional reference to AngularJS (`$scope`)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That could be any variable. I happened to be programming and looking for this answer.  Just an example.

Comment: Whenever i use format, i can't call date() on it. So i had to use some kind of substring construct to grab the day out of a ("DD-MM-YYYY") format.

Comment: This gets a deprecation warning now. FYI: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Comment: @JohnSnow you can use "LLLL" as the second argument in the moment which tells the current date format.
ex - moment(testDate, "LLLL").format('MM/DD/YYYY');

Comment: Take this a step further...

String.prototype.formatDate = function(format = "M/DD/YYYY") {
 return moment(this).format(format);
};

Comment: Works for me, in my case: const initialDate = moment(this.initialDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');

Answer (score 63):

Include moment.js and using the below code you can format your date

```
var formatDate= 1399919400000;

var responseDate = moment(formatDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

My output is "13/05/2014"

Comment: How can I reverse that? I mean if I have the later format and want to change it to the first one.

Comment: @ArslanTariq you can use `momentObject.valueOf()` to get milliseconds from epoch.

Answer (score 43):

```
moment().format();                                // "2019-08-12T17:52:17-05:00" (ISO 8601, no fractional seconds)
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Monday, August 12th 2019, 5:52:00 pm"
moment().format("ddd, hA");                       // "Mon, 5PM"
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* this code solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 23):

### *You Probably Don't Need Moment.js Anymore*

Moment is great time manipulation library but it's considered as a **legacy** project, and the team is recommending to use other [libraries](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/).

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is one of the best lightweight libraries, it's modular, so you can pick the functions you need and reduce bundle size ([issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2373) & [statement](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/)).

> Another common argument against using Moment in modern applications is its size. Moment doesn't work well with modern "tree shaking" algorithms, so it tends to increase the size of web application bundles.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns' // 21K (gzipped: 5.8K)
import moment from 'moment' // 292.3K (gzipped: 71.6K)
```

Format date with `date-fns`:

```
// moment.js
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
// => "12/18/2020"

// date-fns
import { format } from 'date-fns'
format(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
// => "12/18/2020"
```

More on cheat sheet with the list of functions which you can use to replace moment.js: [You-Dont-Need-Momentjs](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs)

Answer (score 15):

```
var moment = require('moment');

let yourdate = '2021-01-02T07:57:45.121Z'; // for example

moment(yourdate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

// output : 01-02-2021


moment(yourdate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');

// output : 01-Jan-2021
```

Answer (score 7):

For fromating output date use `format`. Second moment argument is for parsing - however if you omit it then you `testDate` will cause deprecation warning

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format...

```js
var testDate= "Fri Apr 12 2013 19:08:55 GMT-0500 (CDT)"

let s= moment(testDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

msg.innerText= s;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

to omit this warning you should provide parsing format

```js
var testDate= "Fri Apr 12 2013 19:08:55 GMT-0500 (CDT)"

let s= moment(testDate, 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('MM/DD/YYYY');

console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, first i have to provide identifier (format) of our date format then desire format.  nice example.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass "L" to `format` method, which handles internationalisation...

```
moment.locale('en-US');
moment().format("L");
> "06/23/2021"

moment.locale('fr');
moment().format("L");
> "23/06/2021"
```

Other long date formats (`fr` locale):

```
LT : 'HH:mm',
LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
```

Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ (see "Localized formats")

Answer (score 4):

To get the current UTC time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.Millisecond with timezone using moment format as below

```
moment().utc().format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z').
```

Output

```
2022-09-20 15:28:39.446 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps some one who are looking for multiple date formats one after the other by willingly or unexpectedly.
Please find the code:
I am using moment.js format function on a current date as (today is 29-06-2020)
var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY'); Result: 06/28/20

what happening is it retains only the year part :20 as "06/28/20", after If I run the statement :
new Date(startDate)
The result is "Mon Jun 28 1920 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",

Then, when I use another format on "06/28/20": startDate = moment(startDate ).format('MM-DD-YYYY'); Result: 06-28-1920, in google chrome and firefox browsers it gives correct date on second attempt as: 06-28-2020. But in IE it is having issues, from this I understood we can apply one dateformat on the given date, If we want second date format, it should be apply on the fresh date not on the first date format result.
And also observe that for first time applying 'MM-DD-YYYY' and next 'MM-DD-YY' is working in IE.
For clear understanding please find my question in the link:
[Date went wrong when using Momentjs date format in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622534/date-went-wrong-when-using-momentjs-date-format-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 0):

**[moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)** is a JavaScript library used to manipulate, validate, parse and display dates and times in JavaScript.

Here are common function that used in a project

```js
var now = moment();

let date = "2024-03-29T19:33:36.411Z"; 

const dateTimeUs = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
};
console.log("dateTimeUs => ", dateTimeUs(date));

const dateSimplewithSlashes = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
};
console.log("dateSimplewithSlashes => ", dateSimplewithSlashes(date));

const dateSimplewithDashes = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};
console.log("dateSimplewithDashes => ", dateSimplewithDashes(date));

const ReversedateSimplewithDashes = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
};
console.log("ReversedateSimplewithDashes => ", ReversedateSimplewithDashes(date));

const dateUSWithAlphaMonth = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('DD MMM YYYY');
};
console.log("dateUSWithAlphaMonth => ", dateUSWithAlphaMonth(date));

const getOnlyMonth = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('MMMM');
};
console.log("getOnlyMonth => ", getOnlyMonth(date));

const getOnlyDate = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('DD');
};
console.log("getOnlyDate => ", getOnlyDate(date));

const dateTimeFromNow = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).fromNow();
};
console.log("dateTimeFromNow => ", dateTimeFromNow(date));

const dateSimplewithComma = incomingDate => {
  return moment(incomingDate).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
};
console.log("dateSimplewithComma => ", dateSimplewithComma(date));

const currentTime = incomingTime => {
  return moment(incomingTime).format('hh:mm A');
};
console.log("currentTime => ", currentTime(date));

const MonthNdDate = incomingTime => {
  return moment(incomingTime).format('MMMM DD');
};
console.log("MonthNdDate => ", MonthNdDate(date));

const getOnlyTime = incomingTime => {
  return moment(incomingTime).format('hh:mm A');
};
console.log("getOnlyTime => ", getOnlyTime(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```