# How to get date object from date string format

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert a date string to date format, something like this:

```
var date = "07/11/2015"; //format is mm/dd/yyyy
```

Now I want it to be in this format:

```
date = Tue Sep 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js

Comment: @Manwal, that's for converting to 'mm/dd/yyyy' format? Can you please suggest how to do it's reverse.

Comment: You can convert to any format with Moment.

Comment: @Manwal: Not as many as your could implement natively on your own ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var date = "07/11/2015";
    
alert(new Date(date)); //Sat Jul 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```