# How to convert date into given format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to generate this date format using Moment.js:

```
Mon Apr 1 17:51:40 2019
```

Right now, I am getting this format instead:

```
Mon Apr 01 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for Date object - it's all there

Comment: your problem looks same like this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js.    I hope this will help you..

Comment: I down voted this post because the OP did not have any attempt or code to solve the problem. And probably did not check the documentation of the mentioned library, which would actually have the answer right in the landing page: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @ektasahu , can you tell me how is that answer is correct and you should note the time that how have given the answer first and then you mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
Moment(new Date(this.state.date)).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

or whatever format you want. you can check them on here: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var dateTime = new Date("Mon Apr 01 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0530 (IST)");
 dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already a valid date string - just make a `new Date`:

```js
console.log(new Date("Mon Apr 01 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0530 (IST)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install moment

```
 let formatedDate = moment('Mon Apr 01 2019 17:51:40 GMT+0530 (IST)').format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss YYYY');
 console.log(formatedDate)
```

> output: Mon Apr 01 17:51:40 2019

Done You can check it