# how set the datepicker in moment.js to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am using Moment.js with Angular 8:
I am using the following html:
But I am getting "mm/dd/yyyy" in the input box but I want "yyyy-mm-dd". In moment.js url it stated it should be "yyyy-mm-dd" by default(https://momentjs.com/docs/).

```
  <input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="date" [(ngModel)]="report.startDate" required 
#startDate="ngModel"/>
```

[image]
[image]

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js

Answer (score 2):

The format keyword will allow you to define how you want the date displayed.

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```