# DD/MM/YYY HH:MM AM/PM format using monentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to format my data-string and sent it to the API like - DD/MM/YYY HH:MM AM/PM . How can it be done using momentjs . Please help

Comment: Could you please what have you done so far

Comment: You can also have a look at `.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [format date with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 3):

From the moment docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ , You could use the following formatting options for your  output

```js
console.log(moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a"));// for current moment
let customDate = "28/03/2020 12:34:56";
console.log(moment(customDate, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to the community . But please keep in mind you should show what you have done so far to get help .You can do something like this.

```
const today = moment();
console.log(
  "Today's date is: " + 
  today.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM A')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
moment('24/12/2019 09:15:00', "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A");
```

You should look on [moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) before you try to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY kk:mm A")

For all the formats please check - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/