# Date went wrong when using Momentjs date format in IE 11

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-formatting

I am using Moment.js format function on a current date as

```
var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY');
```

The result is *06/28/20*

What happens is that it retains only the year part: *20* as *"06/28/20"*, after I used `new Date(startDate)`, the result is *"Mon Jun 28 1920 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"*.

After this when I applied another format on *"06/28/20"*:

```
startDate = moment(startDate ).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

The result is *06-28-1920*

In Google Chrome and Firefox it gives the correct date for the second attempt as: *06-28-2020*.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY');
alert("startDate ==="+startDate +"==="+new Date(startDate ));

startDate = moment(startDate ).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
alert("startDate ==="+startDate +"==="+new Date(startDate ));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below snippet , which might help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY');
  alert("startDate ==="+startDate +"==="+new Date(startDate ));
  
  startDate = moment(new Date(startDate)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
  var str="06-28-2020";
  
  
  alert("startDate ==="+startDate +"==="+new Date(str.replaceAll("-","/")));
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Dilip, thanks for the details, here the issue is different which is related to momentjs format method usage as clarified by alpsavrum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Moment, use Moment **only**. Parsing date strings with `Date.parse()` or `new Date(`) (same thing under hood) is not [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Your approach should be using `moment(DATE, "DD/MM/YY")` which handles the 2k year problem you face, automatically.

Comment: Hi @alpsavrum, please explain a little bit more on this, moment.format(dateformat) behaves differently in chrome also for different dateformats 'YY-DD-MMM', 'DD-MM-YY','MM/DD/YY' .

Comment: moment.format is not the right use. use it like moment().format(dateformat). you should construct the moment before using it.

Comment: I converted the line var startDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY') to
var startDate1 = moment(new Date(),'MM/DD/YY'), It is working fine in all browsers. Are you suggesting the same, please confirm.

Comment: Hi @alpsavrum, moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD') results as 2020/06/28(as required format in output)
As per the suggestion I replaced the above line with as:
moment(new Date() ,'YYYY/MM/DD'), but it results 1593368656727, how can we get this value as format 'YYYY/MM/DD'