# Display human readable dateTime format in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

I have react component where I am using useMemo to define table structure. My data is coming via API in DateTime (Web API C#). I tried to use moment to convert date Time format but unable to do so.

current time format without moment   2020-12-18T14:00:00

```
const scheduleColumns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Site ID",
        accessor: "siteId",
      },
      {
        Header: "Start Time",
        accessor: moment("startTime").fromNow(),
      },
    ],
    []
  );
```

..Table

```
    <TableItemsTabs          
        apiUrl={api.myAPI}
        columns={scheduleColumns}
    ></TableItemsTabs>}
```

Comment: But in which format you want to show the date?

Comment: I don't mind but this format will be ideal ... 08/12/2020 23:59

Comment: DD:MM:YYYY Time

Comment: But if you're using moment can't you use `.format()` function provided by it?

Comment: so help me how I can achieve goal.. i am new to react

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js . Can you check if any of these works? And if you're using `moment` for few things then I'd recommend to use `date-fns`, it's a lighter module in comparison to `moment`. In the same link, you can check the answer by @t_dom93

Comment: I have tried this code but not getting result in specify format {
            Header: "Start Time",
            accessor: moment().format("startTime, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
          },

Answer (score 1):

Even found more simpler solution, doesn't even need any module

```
let a = new Date('2020-12-18T14:00:00');
a.toLocaleString('en-GB');
// Output - "18/12/2020, 14:00:00"
```

Comment: i need to use code in inside useMemo as refer in my code? how I can use a.toLocaleString('en-GB');

Comment: In your `useMemo` you can add it like this --> `accessor: new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB');`