# Use moment to format date in a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I have a Vue component with an input field which is a date type:

```html
<input
    type="date"
    name="start_date"
    id="start_date"
    v-model="absence.start_date"
>
```

In my script I am trying to format the date so that it displays correctly:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                absence: {
                    start_date: null,
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            const request = axios
                .get(`/api/absences/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.absence = response.data.data;
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

However it doesn't work with the format returned by the API.

If I set the date manually it works in this format

```
start_date: '2021-01-01',
```

However it is overwritten by the api call. I have moment installed in app.js, how can I use moment to format the date returned by the api call?

**EDIT**

This is the API response:

```js
{"success":true,"data":{"id":1,"start_date":"2021-07-24 00:00:00","end_date":"2021-07-25 00:00:00","notes":"Quis nisi repellendus ipsa. Eum asperiores sunt iusto exercitationem autem. Qui harum adipisci praesentium laboriosam. Fugit quasi voluptatem excepturi et non autem atque quibusdam. Sed aperiam molestias quaerat incidunt.","created_at":"2021-06-28T19:34:16.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-03T15:46:10.000000Z","status":1}}
```

Comment: Please add some more details. How did you design the API? What exactly the API is returning? It looks like the problem is more on the backend API rather than the vue itself.

Comment: `moment(startDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');` would something like this suffice ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js

You can also do moment(startDate).isValid() to see if it is a valid format that moment can take

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the below. Working Sample Code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-meninsky-w0sv2)

And Make sure you install the moment js

```
<input
   type="date"
   name="start_date"
   id="start_date"
   v-model="formattedStartDate"
>
```

---

```
// Make sure moment is installed

<script>
    import moment from 'moment'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                absence: {
                    start_date: null,
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            formattedStartDate() {
                return moment(this.absence.start_date).format('yyyy-MM-DD');
            }
        },
        created() {
            const request = axios
                .get(`/api/absences/${this.$route.params.id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.absence = response.data.data;
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, the Moment.js team recommends that Moment not be used in new projects, and recommends some some alternatives. See https://momentjs.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="date">` only accepts the date portion of an ISO date string as a valid value, but the API data includes the time:

```js
{
  "start_time": "2021-07-24 00:00:00"
                            ^^^^^^^^
}
```

You can easily parse the date from that string with [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the space, taking the first array element (the date):

```js
const data = response.data.data
this.absence = {
  ...data,
  start_date: data.start_date.split(' ')[0]
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-input-date-model?file=src%2FApp.vue)