# convert dateTime format in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

i have this date :

> Mon Aug 23 2021 15:03:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)

how to convert this format:

> 2021-10-10T00:00:00

Comment: Is the first date hardcoded or received from JS ?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario of this conversion? Are you getting the data from database/ userinput?

Comment: I get it from the user(userinput)

Comment: `date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + 'T00:00:00'` 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods

Comment: You can use moment.js : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js

Comment: @zahrazamani Can you explain the "T00:00:00" in the expected output? Is it derived from the input or just a static text?

Comment: The refactored format loses the timezone offset information so represents a different moment in time each place with a different offset. Is that intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
new Date('Mon Aug 23 2021 15:03:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)')
.toISOString().split('.')[0]

=> '2021-08-23T10:33:00'
```

If you don't prefer the native way of converting it you can use the library [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Your code would look as follows:

```
moment('Mon Aug 23 2021 15:03:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)')
.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

=> '2021-08-23T10:33:00'
```

If you don't want to keep the hours, minutes and seconds these examples will work.

Native way:

```
new Date('Mon Aug 23 2021 15:03:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)').toISOString().split('T')[0] + 'T00:00:00'

=> '2021-08-23T10:33:00'
```

With Moment.js:

```
moment('Mon Aug 23 2021 15:03:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)')
.format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00');

=> '2021-08-23T10:33:00'
```

**Edit**

As RobG mentioned in the comments, the **toISOString()** function will return the **UTC** time format. So even one more reason to use moment.js!

Comment: The "native way" returns UTC date and time masquerading as local, it is not a straight conversion of format.

Comment: The issue with *toISOString* isn't a reason to use a library, it's a reason not to use *toISOString* the way it's used here. ;-)

Comment: You can think of it in that way! Its just smarter to use moment.js because it offers more possibilities and flexability, but thank you for your input!