# How to use Moments to change date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, momentjs, date-formatting

I'm working on a project, but I'm facing an issue,i want to change datepicker format to from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-dd-mm the fuction dont work maybe i'm missing somthing, so how to use Moments.js to change date format from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-dd-mm, any help will be appreciated.

here is my code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="birth-date" >BIRTH DATE</label>
    <input type="date"  class="datepicker" name="birth-date" id="birth-date" >
```

// Datepicker

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-dd-mm',
 });
```

//main function work's but dateformat is mm/dd/yyyy

```
const getdate= (db) => { 
return ~~((new Date()-new Date(db))/(31556952000));
};
```

//what i have tried but didn't work

```
const getdate = (db) => {
const date = moment(db, 'yyyy-dd-mm');
return moment().diff(date, 'years');
};
```

Best regards.

Comment: I think you want to do moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY').  Reference https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Yes that's right XD i just had to type it CAPITAL , thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed this :

```
const date = moment(db, 'yyyy-dd-mm');
```

to :

```
const date = moment(db, 'YYYY-DD-MM');
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `format()` method to convert it.

```
const convertedFormat = moment(dob, 'mm/dd/yyyy').format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

**OR**

```
const convertedFormat = moment(dob).format('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

**NOTE:** I recommend you stop using `Moment.js` ([Why?](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)) and use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) instead.